# Removing intrude numbers from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I know this question is simple, however, I am asking to see if there is an optimized way to do that.
I have a dictionary of dataframes (dict), each dataframe in this dictionnary contains a column named (hours_eng), representing registered machine hours with the dates in a second column.
Normally, hours should be in an increasing pattern according to the dates, for example at 1/9/2023 the hours_eng should be equal to 516 and at 3/9/2023 the hours_eng should be for example 677. (or any number larger than 516 using the logic), so they should follow an increasing pattern.
Now, the problem is that these data are filled by humans, and like other things, human intervention could lead to several mistakes, so for example the user filling these data could add a "0" or any number to a certain element, so in this case the vector would be [5, 6, 76, 8] instead of [5, 6, 7, 8], in this case I want to delete the "70" from the vector and let it be [5, 6, 8].

Another example, let us consider that the vector is [5, 6, 3, 70, 9, 12], I want the code to keep [5, 6, 9, 12] and consider the 3 and 70 as outsiders.

I do not know if the question is clear, but I have a vector that contain number that should be increasing, and I want to remove the outsiders and remove their rows from all the dataframes in the dataframe dictionnary.

Comment: 1- please provide a reproducible example of your dataframe, 2- in a case such as `[5, 6, 3, 8, 7, 12]` how do you know if `7` or `8` is the outlier? Are you only aiming at outliers ending with 0?

Comment: As a first step you can use `shift` to create an additional `hours_eng` column shifted by one row and compare to original column which entries are larger to find the bad rows.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add any detail (don't use comments) and make sure to provide several minimal examples to illustrate the logic.

Comment: Which points would you consider outliers in this case? [I identify 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GyOq.png)

Comment: Please post code with a minimal reproducible example with your current output and an example of your expected output.